# Docker says oracle instant client install was successful, but exploring the container's file system there is no 'oracle'

Tags: docker

My docker file looks like this

```
FROM store/oracle/database-instantclient:12.2.0.1

ENV OCI_LIB=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
ENV OCI_INC=/usr/include/oracle/12.2/client64
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${OCI_LIB}
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin

FROM rocker/rstudio
FROM rocker/tidyverse
```

and when I run docker build. I see a message on the console saying the following

```
Step 1/15 : FROM store/oracle/database-instantclient:12.2.0.1
12.2.0.1: Pulling from store/oracle/database-instantclient
497341ef9d71: Pulling fs layer
598d27c2564a: Pulling fs layer
497341ef9d71: Verifying Checksum
497341ef9d71: Download complete
497341ef9d71: Pull complete
598d27c2564a: Verifying Checksum
598d27c2564a: Download complete
598d27c2564a: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:e83a2a223a14f24e6e433847d15d817ff7799a3a1a2dd2e4b224437358e996a0
Status: Downloaded newer image for store/oracle/database-instantclient:12.2.0.1
```

However when I explore the container's file system I do not see reference to 'Oracle' at all in the entire file system.

I do the following for exploring

```
# find ID of your running container:
docker ps

# create image (snapshot) from container filesystem
docker commit 12345678904b5 mysnapshot

# explore this filesystem using bash (for example)
docker run -t -i mysnapshot /bin/bash
```

What's going on..??

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the subsequent `FROM` lines in the Dockerfile (`FROM rocker/rstudio`...) wipe out what has been done. The final container image is what is constructed from the last FROM onward. If you want to carry over things from the image constructed before, you have to explicitly COPY them to your current image. See the [Docker documentation for multistage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

I'm not sure it is going to be practical to retrieve everything required by Oracle in the initial image to copy it over. Maybe you should either:

1. install/add things in the Oracle image.
2. construct the first two images, the the Oracle image, and copy things to the oracle image.
3. have two containers, one with the plain Oracle and one for other stuff, which would be the usual way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following to work.

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim AS oracrap

RUN  yum -y install oracle-release-el7 && yum-config-manager --enable ol7_oracle_instantclient && \
     yum -y install oracle-instantclient18.5-basic oracle-instantclient18.5-devel oracle-instantclient18.5-sqlplus && \
     rm -rf /var/cache/yum && \
     echo /usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient18.5.conf && \
     ldconfig

ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/bin       


FROM rocker/rstudio:3.5.0

COPY --from=oracrap /usr/lib/oracle /usr/lib/oracle/
COPY --from=oracrap /usr/include/oracle /usr/include/oracle/
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/bin:/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib:/usr/include/oracle/18.5/client64/
ENV OCI_LIB=/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib
ENV OCI_INC=/usr/include/oracle/18.5/client64
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64=/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib

RUN ln -s /usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.18.1   libclntsh.so.18.1

FROM rocker/tidyverse:3.5.0

COPY --from=oracrap /usr/lib/oracle /usr/lib/oracle/
COPY --from=oracrap /usr/include/oracle /usr/include/oracle/
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/bin:/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib:/usr/include/oracle/18.5/client64/
ENV OCI_LIB=/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib
ENV OCI_INC=/usr/include/oracle/18.5/client64
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64=/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib

RUN ln -s /usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.18.1  libclntsh.so.18.1
```